# Can Javascript spread operator include undefined fields of an object?

Tags: javascript, operators, spread-syntax

Is there a more readable way of spreading undefined fields of an object on another object without traversing every element of it?

Following example spreads object `A` on object `B`:

```js
let A = { f1:'Foo', f2:'Bar', f3:'Baz' }
let B = { ...A }
// Now B has the value of { f1:'Foo', f2:'Bar', f3:'Baz' }
```

However in the following example spread operator will not include undefined values:

```js
let A = { f1:'Foo', f2:undefined, f3:'Baz' }
let B = { ...A }
// Now B has the value of { f1:'Foo', f3:'Baz' }
// I would like it to be spread like { f1:'Foo', f2:undefined, f3:'Baz' } 
// or { f1:'Foo', f2:null, f3:'Baz' }
```

Is there a way of projecting fields with `undefined` value using spread operator?  (and obviously **WITHOUT** traversing every field of the object `A` and spreading into `B` if the value of that field is not `undefined`)

Comment: i can't reproduce problem. `let A = { f1:'Foo', f2:undefined, f3:'Baz' }
let B = { ...A }` this is giving me expected result only.

Comment: Your assertion is incorrect. If `A` has a field `f2` with *any* value, including `undefined`, it will be copied to `B` by the spread (which is not really an operator, for what that's worth).

Comment: Oh that's right.. I guess it is `Express.js` excluding the fields with undefined upon using `Response::json()`

Comment: @iGoodie that's because `undefined` isn't a legal value in JSON, despite it being a legal value of a key in a JS literal.

Comment: That makes perfect sense @Alnitak ! Thanks everybody

Comment: Note that while undefined is illegal, null is a valid value in JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be an invalid assertion of mine. Spread operator indeed spreads fields with `undefined` value. It was `JSON.stringify()` removing those fields within one of my sources, which lead me to an invalid assertion.

For `Express.js` users; you can use `app.set('json replacer', (k, v) => v===undefined ? null : v);` to let express stringify your json response by replacing `undefined` values with `null`

Or likewise, you can use `JSON.stringify({...}, (k, v) => v===undefined ? null : v)` to let it stringify by replacing `undefined` values with `null`

Answer (score 3):

If you're asking if the spread operator will maintain undefined property values 'post spread', they do.

```js
const original = { one: 1, two: 2, three: undefined, four: null };
console.log(original);
const withSpread = {five: 5, ...original };
console.log(withSpread);
console.log(typeof withSpread.three === 'undefined')
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax